# True or False: $\{1\}\subset\bigcap\{\{\mathbb{N}\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(That is supposed to be the big intersection symbol for set family.)

I’m not sure if this is false because 1 is not a subset of $\{\mathbb{N}\}$. But aren‘t $\mathbb{N}$ and $\varnothing$ elements of $\{\mathbb{N}\}$? Elements of the left side are elements of the right side, making it true?

Comment: No. $A$ is a subset of $B$ if every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$. I think the confusion here might be because you think the empty set is an element of {1}. But this is not the case: The empty set is a *subset* of {1}. Secondly, when you say: "Elements of the left side are elements of the right side". This is not true. $1$ is not an element of the RHS.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is not an element of $\{\Bbb N\}$, but $\Bbb N$ is.

Comment: The notation is confusing me. What is that intersection on the right side? By $\{\mathbb{N}\}$, do you mean the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$? Usually I see the powerset denoted as $P(\mathbb{N})$. Or perhaps you mean the single element set which contains $\mathbb{N}$ as its only element?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulios The symbol on the right is, as stated, $\bigcap A:=\{x\mid \forall y\in A, x\in y\}$. This is somewhat standard (although some use $\bigcap A:=\left\{x\in V\,:\, \forall y\in A, x\in y\right\}$ when it is given by context that the scope of the discussion are the subsets of some $V$). $\{\Bbb N\}$ is unambiguously the singleton containing $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thank you. That's what I would normally assume, but I guess I was thrown off by op's comment about $\emptyset\in\mathbb{\{N\}}$ and I couldn't believe we were simply supposed to have an intersection of just a single set... I expected something more...

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the notation correctly, consider for instance the set $$A=\{1,2\}$$ we would usually say that $A$ has two elements, 1 and 2, but there are 4 possible subsets, namely, $A,\{1\},\{2\},\varnothing$. With this in mind
$$\bigcap\{\{\mathbb{N}\}\}=\{\mathbb{N}\}$$
since $\{\{\mathbb{N}\}\}$ contains only one element, $\{\mathbb{N}\}$. Finally the only subsets of $\{\mathbb{N}\}$ are $\mathbb{N}$ and $\varnothing$, so $\{1\}\nsubseteq\{\mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: I would replace $\subsetneq$ with $\nsubseteq$.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent are the statements:

- $\{1\}\subseteq\bigcap\{\{\mathbb N\}\}$
- $\forall x\in\{1\}\left[x\in\bigcap\{\{\mathbb N\}\}\right]$
- $1\in\bigcap\{\{\mathbb N\}\}$
- $\forall x\in\{\{\mathbb N\}\} [1\in x]$
- $1\in\{\mathbb N\}$
- $1=\mathbb N$

Evidently the last is false so we conclude that also the first is false.